# Database Architecture For E-Commerce Solution

Tags: sql-server

I have many important question about E-Commerce solution database :

1. For validation your form fields, for example (Null Value can not be inserted , Unique value , just number input, Date validation and etc.)

   what's the best way :

   a) Use function with T-SQL in my database on the table fields and handle with Try-Catch
   b) Use .NET validation component
   c) Use Ajax component
   d) Use businesses method
2. If I use Entity Framework, should I use stored procedures or I can use insert, update and delete method from Entity Framework?

   Which one is the best way for E-Commerce solution ?
3. For E-Commerce solution we should 3 or 5 step normalization or create Flat table ?
4. For E-Commerce solution Linq To Sql or Entity Framework ? which one and why ?

These are very important questions for me

Thanks

Comment: This is way too broad to answer properly. In general: prefer Entity Framework over Linq-to-SQL (won't be developed any further), and I would prefer Linq-to-Entities over stored procedures. Also: always normalize your database to third normal form and then possibly denormalize again here and there where performance issues can be solved by that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right answer is more nuanced.  The 'best' way means validating at many places along the way.

You should validate in the form using JavaScript/jQuery.  Tell users about required values, improper formats, etc.

Controllers should bind and validate values they receive.

Services should never trust a UI.  They also have additional information that a UI can never have: business rules for validity.  Those are context-dependent and may change.  Let the execution of business rules be done by the middle tier services.

Validating in the database, using constraints like UNIQUE, triggers or stored procedures, should be the last resort and only used if the database is shared by several applications.  I wouldn't want to wait until I was persisting data to find out that it was invalid.  The earlier you can inform a user, the better.